# What could be the reason for stem this far away

Tags: stem, design

I own a bicycle similar to this one:

[image: Corratec Jazzbow]

(I replaced the handlebars with straight one on mine)

I know that there were some weird designs back in '90s, but some reason probably exists for creating a bike with such a long stem. Doesn't it create uncomfortable riding position?

Comment: Perhaps the previous owner was too tall for the frame and was trying to compensate with a longer stem.

Comment: The longer forward extension produces a more prone (aerodynamic) position and, in theory, more stability.  And it better suits a person with a long trunk.

Comment: There are also trekking bars on that bike - if they were installed horizontally towards the rider, they would be a lot closer as well.

Comment: @Kibbee: I'm pretty sure that these are factory installed stems, so something that should be planned for an average rider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the bars were rotated back, they would not be so far away. And, if you wanted to tuck down and get more aerodynamic you could reach the part of the bar that is further away.

Comment: What's the recommended (or usual) position for this kind of bars?

Comment: @MladenJablanović Angled back